# Loading a relationship from a "RESTful" url

Tags: ember.js, relationships

I am trying to figure out how to load a relationship of an object through a sub-resource route using EmberJS.

For example: the url I need to hit on the api is `/workspace/:workspace_id/projects`, which will return an array of projects related to the workspace. EmberJS is best suited to work with single-level resources, so if I try and do `this.store.find('project')`, a GET request is fired to `/projects`.

I have some context for the request, as the url where the request will from from is `/workspace/:workspace_id`. My gut instinct is to use window.location.pathname in a custom adapter to build the proper request URL.

What would be the proper, "Ember way" of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define the `Projects` relationship on `Workspace` as async and then provide the link the right URL to find the workspace's projects. For instance, the response from the endpoint `/workspace/1` would be:

```
{
  workspace: {
    id: 1,
    links: {
      projects: "https://example.com/api/workspace/1/projects"
    }
  }
}
```

Then if somewhere in the code you would do

```
this.store.find('workspace', 1).get('projects')
```

Ember Data will know that the workspace's projects can be found at the link you provided in the JSON response, i.e. "https://example.com/api/workspace/1/projects".

Does this help?

Comment: I thought ember-data would find the related objects only if you provided the ID's of the relations. See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships

Comment: The guide is a bit incomplete in that respect and sometimes you have to dig into the API to find "hidden" gems. See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany for the functionality I'm talking about.